# How to remove the frame around my Cartopy/Matplotlib plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

So I am running this code for plotting a map, and no matter what I try I can't get rid of the ugly box/frame scaled 0 to 1. When I get rid of the figure frame, it refers to the inner one with lat/long that I want to keep.

```
df = days_dict[t]
    proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
    bounds = [-125.0011, -66.9326, 49.5904, 24.9493]
    ax.set_extent(bounds, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    im = ax.scatter(df['long'], df['lat'], c=df['mean_no2'], s=8, cmap=cm.bwr, vmin=0, vmax=40)
    cartography(ax)
    
    axins = inset_axes(ax, width="90%", height="10%", loc='lower center', borderpad=-3)
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar(im, label='NO2 concentration (ppb)', orientation='horizontal', cax=axins, fraction=0.046, norm=norm, anchor=(0.5, -1))
    cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 40, 10))
    plt.show()
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.bbox_inches='tight'
    
    fig.frameon = False
    axins.frameon = False
    out_name = out_folder + '\\frame%s.png' % t
    
    fig.savefig(out_name)
    fig.clear()
```

I want the inner frame, but not the outer. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `plt.box(False)` with `plt.xticks([])` and  `plt.yticks([])`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises by the existence of `cartography(ax)` in your code.
Just replace it by this line of code:-

```
ax.gridlines(xlocs=range(-180,180,10),ylocs=range(-90, 90, 10),color='black',linestyle='dotted',draw_labels=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(true_scale_latitude = 75)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
ax.coastlines('10m')
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 65, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image: Weird frame]

Solution:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), subplot_kw={"projection": ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(true_scale_latitude = 75)})
    ax.coastlines('10m')
    ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 65, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image: No weird frame]